# "Any $\mathrm{End}(S)$-module is of the form $W\otimes S$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I am currently reading the book [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628) and I am facing the following problem:

Let $S$ be a complex and finite-dimensional vector space and $E$ a finite-dimensional $\mathrm{End}(S)$-module. The proof of proposition $3.27$ says that this means that

> $E$ is of the form $S\otimes W$.

It sounds like they are referring to some standard result from algebra, can someone please elaborate and/or name a reference?

**Edit**: I guess that what they really mean is that we can find a complex vector space $W$ together with an isomorphism $E\to S\otimes W$ of $\mathrm{End}(S)$-modules , where the action of $\mathrm{End}(S)$ on $S\otimes W$ is simply given by
$$A\cdot(s\otimes w)=A(s)\otimes w.$$
What do you think?

Comment: Is E a left or right End(S)-module?

Comment: @FShrike I don't think that they make this distinction, but I would say left module.

Comment: @FShrike I thought that this is merely a convention, am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure your book doesn't assume $S$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: _I thought that this is merely a convention_ Merely as in "it doesn't matter" which you pick?  For noncommutative rings, it can mean the difference between two very different categories of modules. However, I'm not sure it's important here.

Comment: @rschwieb The $S$ in the book is finite-dimensional. I didn't know whether this is relevant to the question.

Comment: @rschwieb You mean that if the ring is not commutative, then there is not a trivial 1 to 1 correspondance between left and right modules?

Comment: @Filippo No meaningful correspondence, no.

Comment: *I didn't know whether this is relevant to the question.*  If there are any more assumptions relevant to the question, please give them up front. It's a bit off-putting for readers to have the surprises sprung later, or to have to have them pried out of the question-asker.

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry, $E$ and $S$ can both be assumed to be finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

A ring theorist would say that $R=End(S)$ is a semisimple ring, and as such, $S$ is the unique simple module of $R$.

Since every $R$ module is a direct sum simple modules (that's a characterizing property of semisimple rings) and the only simple module is $S$, $E$ has to be a sum of copies of $S$, and its dimensionality would wind up being some multiple of $\dim(S)$, or else some infinite cardinal.

If the dimension of $E$ is $n\dim(S)$, then you can pick $W$ to be any $n$ dimensional space so that $S\otimes_\mathbb C W$ has the right dimension to be isomorphic (as vector spaces) to $E$.  If the dimension of $E$ is some infinite cardinal, then you can just pick $W$ to have the same dimension as $E$.

The $R$ module structure it gets from $\oplus_{i\in I} S$ can be given to $S\otimes_\mathbb C W$, but I'm not sure why it's any more useful than regarding it as $\oplus_{i\in I} S$. The action you described does make $S\otimes_\mathbb C W$ into a left $R$ module, and owing to the dimensionality it would be isomorphic to the direct sum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Since I have very little background in algebra, I need to ask for a confirmation of something that will seem obvious to you: When you talk about the module $S$, is the multiplication
$$\begin{align} \mathrm{End}(S)\times S&\to S\\ (A,s)&\mapsto A\cdot s \end{align}$$
simply the evaluation, i.e. $A\cdot s:=A(s)$?

Comment: @Filippo Yes, a right $R$ module $S$ has a natural left $End(S_R)$ module action on the left given by exactly that.  If $S$ is a left $R$ module instead, one gets a right $End(_RS)$ module action.